# Why <slot item={child} /> is needed for the nested object to be displayed if <slot item={item} /> is present?

Tags: recursion, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3

This question is in reference to

[Pass in a slot to a recursive component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73737820/pass-in-a-slot-to-a-recursive-component)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/710718b4c8424ea19ac87f8997d96696?version=3.50.1)

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import Tree from './Tree.svelte';

    const items = [
        {
            type: 'person', first: 'Maru', last: 'Doe',
            children: [
                { type: 'person', first: 'Pochi', last: 'Doe' },
                { type: 'person', first: 'Tama', last: 'Doe' },
                { type: 'thing', manufacturer: 'ACME', product: 'missiles' },
            ]
        }
    ]
</script>

<Tree {items} let:item>
    {#if item.type == 'person'}
        {item.last}, {item.first}
    {:else if item.type == 'thing'}
        {item.product} ({item.manufacturer})
    {/if}
</Tree>
```

Tree.svelte

```
<script>
    export let items;
    export let level = 0;
</script>

<div style:margin-left="{level * 20}px">
    {#each items as item}
        {(console.log({item}),'')}  ---> all items are shown here
        <slot item={item} />
        <svelte:self items={item.children ?? []} level={level + 1}
                                 let:item={child}>
            <slot item={child} />
        </svelte:self>
    {/each}
</div>
```

In Tree.svelte, if we remove `<slot item={child} />` only the parent item is shown i.e. Maru Doe.

But we have the following line(in Tree.svelte) `<slot item={item} />` and if we console print `item` we get all the items i.e. Pochi, Tama, ACME. Should `<slot item={item} />` not pass `item` to the parent (App.svelte) for the items to be printed in each recursion?

So, why are these not displayed when removing <slot item={child} />?
When is `<slot item={child} />` called? Is it like this, svelte:self calls itself recursively and when the last child object is reached, `<slot item={child} />` is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary for recursion.

If the `<svelte:self>` does not have any content (regardless of whether that is a `<slot>` or something else), it will not know how to display the items as that is passed onto `<slot>` within the component.

So if that is not set, the upper `<slot>` definition is used to render the items at the current level, but for any children of these items, nothing will be specified.

`<slot item={child} />` is not just used for some specific item, it is used for all items that are passed in via `<svelte:self items={item.children ?? []} ...`.
In the template that is this:

```html
{#each items as item}
    <slot item={item} />
```

You could think of it as a function like this, maybe that helps:

```js
function tree(items, render) {
    for (const item of items) {
        render(item);

        // `render` needs to be passed again
        tree(item.children ?? [], render);
    }
}
```

Comment: But https://svelte.dev/examples/svelte-self, doesn't have a slot in svelte:self. It's the "else statement" that is displaying items in that example. Your function tree makes sense, we have a tree recursion and everything is displayed in the line: render(item). Do you mean that it's as if "<slot item={child} />" is being passed to svelte:self and it is being used by "<slot item={item} />" deep in the recursion, because that's what render is doing?

Comment: Yes, it just passes it on, the slot is passed into the tree's slot.

Comment: In svelte, is it common for definition of elements to be overloaded? E.g. with slot we pass data from parent to child e.g. App.svelte passes "items" to Tree.svelte. Here Tree.svelte (child) also passes back item to its parent. And, we have <slot item={child} /> being passed to its children.

Comment: Would not call it overloaded, it's more like parameterization. It depends on the type of component. For layouts it is common to have a slot for the content of the page, for components that render multiple items it is also common to have slot properties. In Svelte 5 it should be a bit easier to follow with the introduction of "snippets", there the snippet for the children could be passed directly as a property to `svelte:self`, similar to my function example.